# VMWare Virtual Disk files (.vmdk) from Snapshots piling up, cannot delete without breaking VM

Tags: snapshot, diskspace, vmware-workstation, vmdk

I'm using VMware Workstation Pro 15.5.1 with monolithic disk files (on a Win 10 host).
I worked with snapshots, but always deleted them again because they're not needed anymore.

Unfortunately, it does not delete the Snapshot files from my disk, when I try to delete them by hand it says `This file is required to power on this virtual machine. If this file was moved, specify the new location`.

In my virtual machine settings, I see that disk is about ~58GB in size, which corresponds pretty much exactly to my 000011.vmdk file in the image below. How can I get rid of all the other files?

Thanks!

[image: .vmdk files in my folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/57015 - option 2 (manual consolidation). This resulted in a ~75GB .vmdk file which works independently from the snapshot files.